# Why Do planets Rotate while Sun As a massive Body Don't

Tags: gravity

We all are Very much familiar with the rotation Of Planets about their Own Axis But Someday i thought That if Planets Like Earth , Mars , Jupiter ets.. Rotate why not Sun Rotate around its Own Axis ??

Comment: copied and pasted your own question into google: [Sun Rotate around its Own Axis](https://www.google.es/search?q=Sun+Rotate+around+its+Own+Axis&oq=Sun+Rotate+around+its+Own+Axis&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can easily be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: Why do you think that the sun doesn't rotate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does: its period is not completely well-defined because it is not solid, but is around 25 days.

It is very easy to look this up with a search engine: I am not sure why you did not do so.

Comment: What Would You Say Regarding Jupiter Then and other Gases made Planets Which do Rotate At Fixed Rate ..

Comment: @AkshayWazir: I don't know the story behind that: perhaps they have well-defined solid cores (I think they do).  An astrophysicist would know, I guess.

Comment: that Was Help Full